# The next movie in this series is..?

Tags: pattern, visual, rebus

Here is a series of movies that have something in common other than being thoroughly entertaining.

[image: Find the next movie in this series]

Find the next movie in this series.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Next in sequence is

> "Ace of aces" or "Ace Ventura" (Ace)

The sequence can also be extended in the other direction:

> [Ten Things I Hate About You](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0147800/)
>  [Nine Months](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113986/)
>  [The Hateful Eight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3460252/)
>  [The Magnificent Seven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054047/)
>  [The Six Billion Dollar Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4180298/)

Comment: @Gamow Or any movie with ace in it.  Aces Wild?  Aces High?  Maybe there is another clue...

Comment: It's probably the second one, each one refers to a character and it also alternates from the first word to the second word etc

Comment: ♬ *Five, Gooooooolden Dragons* ♬

Comment: I might suggest:  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086379/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_17  ;)

Comment: ♬ *Faaantastic Four, Three Men and a Baby, Two for the Money, and One Flew Over the Cuckoooo's Neeeeeeeeest.* ♬

Comment: "ten things I hat about you" Normally, I'd edit. But that's just too beautiful of a typo to ruin with correction.

Comment: While we're at it, there's *Jumpin' Jack Flash*, *Jack*, *Kangaroo Jack*, *Priscilla, Queen of the Desert*, *Confessions of a Teenage Drama Queen*, *Queen*, *Kingsman: The Secret Service*, *Return of the King*, *The King's Speech*, *The Fisher King*...  Now I want a deck of cards with movie posters on them...

Answer (score 7):

Next movie is:

> Ace Ventura

Because in every movie:

> Movie names are J,Q,K & A and in each movie character name/title is in movie title : **Jack** Reacher , Snow **Queen** , **King** Kong , **Ace** Ventura

Comment: The Snow Queen and Frozen are different movies.

Comment: Wow this was hard for me. I had to re-read several times before getting the connection among the flicks .. even *with* the answer in hand.