# A Soap and Bond... James Bond

Tags: visual, rebus

REBUS (or shall I call it Brainf*ck).

Look at the following and tell me what particular word or phrase it conveys.

> [image]

Hint:

> The brand of the soap is of no significance.
>  Also, this has a specific relationship with one of my previous puzzles that have garnered most views.

Another
Hint:

> Even Soaps have to change their form when someone has a Licence like Bond.

I have given it all away now. :\

Comment: Is james bond a Soap opera? :O

Comment: Nope, He's MI6, 007,Britain's agent.. Remember.

Comment: You got me on that one... ;)

Comment: Is this a classical rebus (where the answer-word is composed of two pieces encoded in the two pictures), or is it a two-step puzzle (where the pictures just encode hints that then guide you to the answer)?

Comment: two peices encoded in two pictures, with a bit of lateral thinking involved to find the pieces. :)

Comment: OK so - given that @Gamow's original answer is not what you're looking for, just spitballing here: I think there needs to be a clue of some type on puzzles like these alluding to the nature of the answer. Just giving two pictures and saying "what could this be?" is almost the definition of Too Broad.

Comment: Would you mind editing the puzzle and moving the puzzle content out of a spoiler tag?  It's not really a puzzle when the whole thing's hidden. :P @Prashant

Comment: Here's a query to find Prashant's most viewed posts: https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/452458/prashant

Comment: @Justin Oooh, cool! I didn't know about the data explorer.

Comment: Likewise - thanks @Justin.  Here's a clickable version. =D https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/452494/prashant

Comment: Wow. That is cool @justin and Khale_Kitha.. But this doesn't seem to have current data. Criminal Jack and 5000th post is also there as most views which are not visible. Data being fetched seems to be old too, because the movies puzzle is showing 2k+ in my profile

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I see this right, but... does this Mr. Bond have Vulcan ears??

Comment: @Prashant Darn... I was trying to figure out how I could find which one of your questions had had a lot of views, but I didn't you had asked those questions with a lot of views within a couple of days, so yeah, the query is going to return old data, since it is only updated every now and then

Comment: @MaxD No, just large ears and a hairdo that covers part of the visible one.

Comment: Gosh, it seems like the solution to this puzzle is a slippery one. ;)

Comment: The names Bond, Covalent Bond.

Comment: @InternetHobo Ironically, I was working on something to do with superglue... rofl

Comment: @Khale_Kitha that could be it. Superglue is a *bond*ing *agent*. Though, I don't think the answer would be a crude pun like "soap or glue".

Comment: @Ghapla , xnor, CodeNewBie etc. I am sorry I was not available,while enjoying the weekend. But I don't understand why this was put on hold as too broad. The confirmed answer perfectly fits,better than any assumptions previously made.

Comment: Could someone please let me know, why this post is getting downvoted without anyone citing a reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's

> Serial Killer

Reasoning:

> James Bond is famously known as a "double oh" agent (**00**7), which means he has a license to kill.  He is a killer.  (Prashant, I got that part before you posted that extra clue ;) ).  I think the soap is a red herring, the fact that they are bars of soap is less important than the fact that there are two items next to each other, forming a **series**.  Hence serial killer, which, as per the initial clue, also directly relates to Prashant's most viewed question which references Jack the Ripper, a famous serial killer.

Comment: Perhaps it is: soap -> soap opera -> serial

Comment: Oh yeah!  Nice, I hadn't thought of that angle, but that would make sense too.

Comment: AND! There are 2 soaps, and Bond is 007, together that is 2007... A movie (topic of 1 of 3 confirmed possibilities the hint refers to) released in that year was Zodiac, about a serial killer. :D

Comment: Nicely done @feelinferrety, nicely done.

Answer (score 16):

My guess is that it's

> A Cleaning Agent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleaning_agent)

Because

> Soap is used for cleaning, and James Bond is a secret Agent

Comment: Hi, this also was my original (first) answer; you can find it in the edit history of my post.

Comment: @Gamow. I see that now. If you prefer, you can restore your original answer, and add then your second answer as a new answer.  Then your votes would maybe better reflect the answers at the time of voting, and I would be happy to delete this one.

Comment: No, no, no, just keep your answer.  It is good to have it in a separate posting.

Answer (score 14):

**My second try:** The answer might be

> **WS-Security** (Web Services Security, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security)

Argument:

> 1. SOAP is an acronym for Simple Object Access Protocol, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP
>  2. James Bond is a member of the internal **Security Service** MI5
>  3. WS-Security is an extension to SOAP to apply security to Web services.
>  4. WS-Security is related to http; you had a very successful puzzle on http ([Musical Chemistry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/musical-chemistry))

Comment: Nope! Sorry! Not clean at all I'd say.

Comment: Rightly stated.Edit has been made.

Comment: Agree with gamow. Somehow it seems unlikely that there's a better fitting answer, although I'm prepared to be proven wrong.

Comment: I really like this answer, but like @astralfenix, I'm willing to believe there's a better one (and very curious to know what it is)

Comment: @Gamow I liked your previous answer over this one and deleted mine because mine was nonsensical. According to OP's edit its related to "puzzles that have garnered most views." Hence I think its more related to: "http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28493/the-next-movie-in-this-series-is" or "http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28912/criminal-jack-is-here-to-haunt" or "http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29068/the-5000th-question". Could you try to figure it out? You thought process seems much faster than mine. :)

Comment: @Ghapla Yes.! It is way too closely related to one of these. And to me, It may be like giving the answer away if I pinned it down.

Comment: The 5000th question has 7 days of the week... 007?

Answer (score 7):

Changing form suggests

> Reducing agent. Bond is a secret agent and the soap is getting smaller.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at this on the page, I'm not really happy with it. I feel like I'm just guessing. Also, if this is the answer, the rebus would be better without the Pierce Brosnan picture.

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> Bar Bonding, like when friends go to a bar and the bond over a couple of drinks.

Argument:

> it's a soap bar and not liquid soap, and it's a picture of James BOND

Comment: Also, this question was asked today, while yesterday was St. Patty's day so I can see where the idea came from

Answer (score 4):

Not better than Gamow's first answer, but different.

> Clean cut
>  Going clockwise top to bottom in the first picture we can see that the bar of soap is unwrapped and used to clean. The actor's name is Pierce Brosnan and piercing is a form of cutting. I am further swayed in this direction by OP's reference to Bond in the title which seems too obvious to be anything other than a red herring.

Comment: Nice!  But Prashant also told us: "Nope! Sorry! Not clean at all I'd say."

Comment: @Gamow Hmm. Yes. I don't know what to make of that. Could he be suggesting it goes counterclockwise and the soap picture means "unclean" or "dirty" or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> **Pears Soap**? Here is the link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pears_(soap)

Explanation:

> Pierce + Soap ~ Pears saop

Comment: If this goes in the right direction, then it might be some wordplay around "pears" (soap) and "pierce" (Brosnan) and perhaps "pairs" or "peers".

Comment: Yes that's true. I'm afraid we'll need more clarification on this from Prashant

Comment: @Gamow : If it goes into wordplay in this direction it can relate to "Bath" as well. Bro"snan"- Snan is the Sanskrit word for "Bathe", but i can't recall a suitable word other than "Soap Bath" which seems to literal. :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is Rebus-y enough, but:

> Tailor of Old Bond Street

Explanation:

> The picture is not of the current Bond actor, but of an **old Bond.** Tailor of Old Bond Street is a shaving company well known for their **soap**... but that's not a Rebus connection.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a long shot...

> Soap protocol

Justification

> Soap - soap
>  Bond has a license to kill
>  Bond is a professional
>  Bond is a pro-to-kill

And at this point, my hands are full of very wet straw.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another thing that comes to my mind.

> **Die Another Day**

Explanation:

> Dyes(colorants) are used to make soap. It's a bond movie, and I can relate it to your puzzle [5000th Question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29068/the-5000th-question%22) as there are days and its just another day.

Answer (score 1):

Is it?

> No rest for the wicked.

Because:

> There are two type of Web Services: SOAP or Simple Object Access Protocol and REST or Representational State Transfer.
>  And something to do with users or administrators having "licence to kill" or the privilege to stop apps/programs on the server?
>  It's also like your most viewed puzzle who's answer is "No peace for the wicked".

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not the answer, but I'll give it a shot.

It is:

> USB.

It's first letters of

> **U**npacked **S**oap and **B**ond.